# Extract a slice of a large multi-dimensional array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, slice

I'm playing around with some data I got from [Google Takeout](https://www.google.com/settings/takeout). I have an array with 350,000 entries. The data is in this format:

```
[
  {
     "timestampMs": 1296636091733,
     "latitude": 53.548885,
     "longitude": 9.987395
  },
  {
     "timestampMs": 1296635573374,
     "latitude": 53.548676,
     "longitude": 9.987308
  },
  {
     "timestampMs": 1296633598256,
     "latitude": 53.5487,
     "longitude": 9.98749
  } 
]
```

The file is 40mb and I am using [D3.js](https://github.com/mbostock/d3) to plot some subsets of the data. I'm trying to figure out how I could select a date range from that array. Slice gives me the ability to grab a part of the array, but which D3 or Javascript method can I use to find matching start and end entries given a date range (considering the size of the dataset).

Comment: Is the array always sorted by the timestamps?

Comment: @adeneo Assume, yes. It looks that way but I can re-order the json file if not.

Comment: Well, if you're going to have to sort it, you might as well filter, which is why I asked, something like `arr.filter(function(x) { x.timestamp > from && x.timestamp < to });`

Comment: @adeneo thanks! I didn't expect it to be so quick. Against 350k it took just over a second. Would you change your answer if array was already ordered by timestamp? p.s. I added "return" ```a.filter(function(x) { return x.timestampMs > 1296633496671 && x.timestampMs < 1415894666875 })```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've played around the data, which was close to your. I had a log table (ascending timestamps) with ~350k of records. I dumped it into csv and wrote a [benchmark.js](http://benchmarkjs.com/) suite to slice  ~10% range of it (see below). I have the following results on my laptop:

**Firefox**

```
Array.prototype.filter x 38.42 ops/sec ±0.79% (64 runs sampled)
Full crossfilter.js x 11.85 ops/sec ±18.42% (30 runs sampled)
Prepared crossfilter.js x 1,196 ops/sec ±9.70% (69 runs sampled)
Binary search x 3,525 ops/sec ±4.51% (45 runs sampled)
Fastest: Binary search
```

**Chromium**

```
Array.prototype.filter x 33.34 ops/sec ±2.34% (44 runs sampled)
Full crossfilter.js x 5.23 ops/sec ±6.74% (17 runs sampled)
Prepared crossfilter.js x 1,321 ops/sec ±11.90% (95 runs sampled)
Binary search x 22,172 ops/sec ±1.25% (95 runs sampled)
Fastest: Binary search
```

A note about [crossfilter.js](https://github.com/square/crossfilter). It's not exactly a part of D3, but a member of the family (written also by Mike Bostock). Its goal is quick filtering and grouping of multi-dimensional data. So in case you would like to slice your data interactively, it's exactly what you need. However if performance is an absolute priority and you can guarantee that data is sorted, then you'd like to adapt [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) like in example below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
  <title>Sorted list date range performance comparison</title>
    <script src='http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='http://square.github.io/crossfilter/crossfilter.v1.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='http://rawgithub.com/bestiejs/benchmark.js/v1.0.0/benchmark.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function log(message)
    {
      document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += message + '\n';
    }
    function getTimestamp(item)
    {
      return item.timestamp;
    }
    function binarySearch(array, key, left, right)
    {
      var middle, result;
      while(left <= right && array[left] <= key && key <= array[right])
      {
        result = middle = left + Math.floor((right - left) / 2) 
        if(key > array[middle])
        {
          left = middle + 1;
        }
        else if(key < array[middle])
        {
          right = middle - 1;
          if(key > array[right])
          {
            result = right;
            break;
          }        
        }
        else
        {
          break;
        }
      }
      return result;
    }

    // replace to d3.json for a JSON source
    d3.csv('log.csv', function(data)
    {
      data.forEach(function(item)
      {
        item.timestamp = Number(item.timestamp);
      });

      // this should give ~35k entries which is 10% of the dataset
      var start  = Math.floor(new Date('2013-01-01').valueOf() / 1000);
      var finish = Math.floor(new Date('2013-04-01').valueOf() / 1000);

      var dataset   = crossfilter(data);
      var dimension = dataset.dimension(getTimestamp);

      var timestampArray = data.map(getTimestamp);

      new Benchmark.Suite()
        .add('Array.prototype.filter', function() 
        {
          var result = data.filter(function(item)
          {
            return item.timestamp >= start && item.timestamp < finish;
          });
          console.assert(result.length == 34694);
        })
        .add('Full crossfilter.js', function() 
        {
          var dataset   = crossfilter(data);
          var dimension = dataset.dimension(function(item)
          {
            return item.timestamp;
          });
          var result = dimension.filterRange([start, finish]);
          console.assert(result.top(Infinity).length == 34694);
        })
        .add('Prepared crossfilter.js', function() 
        {
          var result = dimension.filterRange([start, finish]);
          console.assert(result.top(Infinity).length == 34694);
        })
        .add('Binary search', function() 
        {
          var left   = binarySearch(timestampArray, start, 0, data.length - 1);
          var right  = binarySearch(timestampArray, finish, 0, data.length - 1);
          var result = data.slice(left + 1, right + 1);
          console.assert(result.length == 34694);
        })          
        .on('cycle', function(event) 
        {
          log(event.target);
        })
        .on('complete', function() 
        {
          log('Fastest: ' + this.filter('fastest').pluck('name'));
        })        
        .run({'async': true});
    });
  </script> 
</head>
<body>
  <pre id='output'></pre>
</body>
</html>
```